# .NET 6 API method is not working after migration to .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webapi, .net-6.0

I have the following API Method that was working fine before .NET 6 migration.

```
[Route("employee/update")]
[HttpPut]
[JwtAuthentication]
public async Task<IActionResult> Put([FromQuery] int id, Employee employee){
....
}
```

This is how I was calling it from `Blazor` app:

```
httpResponse = await Http.PutAsJsonAsync($"employee/update?id={Employee.Id}", employeeModel);
```

The code is never into the API method and I get on `Blazor` a `httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode = false` 400 Http Error Bad Request.

Any clue on what changed in the framework that I have to change?

Comment: If you remove `[JwtAuthentication]` does the Put fire?

Comment: Same thing. Is not the Jwt attribute

Comment: This is using client side blazor right?

Comment: Does your browser console show anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are using json, you have to add frombody attribute

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Put([FromQuery] int id,[FromBody] Employee employee)
```

Comment: Well found out something, was not only the FromBody but also that in .NET 6 is required that you send all properties for a model or set to nullable the ones that can be null. Seems this is new and don't know if this is a configuration that can be changed as before.

Comment: @VAAA Nothing is new it was always  the same since v.1 . Nullables you can disconnect forever in project settings. It was stupid for Ms to add them, as well as it is  very silly to use id and viewmodel together.

Comment: yes the user id and viewmodel together is silly i just removed that. Do you know how to disconnect the nullables in the project settings? Thanks

Comment: @VAAA open project properties file and comment <!--<Nullable>enable</Nullable>--> or remove this.